# Calculating spring constant c

Tags: physics, mathematics, spring

Suppose we have 2 springs with different values for `m` and `k`. The first spring is given an arbitrary dampening value, `c`, to slow it to a stop. How can we calculate `c` for the second spring such that both springs would both stop together?

I realise that mathematically the spring never truly stop and just keeps oscillating infinitely while the amplitude decreases. So I suppose the question is how you would determine a `c` value for the second spring that would cause its amplitude to converge with that of the first spring.

Force is calculated as follows:

`F = (c * -v + -k * (pos - 100) + externalForce)`, where `100` equals the length of the string at rest. Starting position is `100` and a constant external force is applied in random intervals for a random number of timesteps. Otherwise, `externalForce = 0`, and the spring slows to a stop. It should be noted that the externalForce may be applied while the spring is still in motion.

Comment: Be sure to include the formula that includes c in your definition, and the initial momentum and displacement of each spring

Comment: @DMGregory, changes made.

Comment: Now you'll need to define external force and how it varies over its period (of what?).

Comment: @DMGregory, I hope that clarifies things :)

Comment: We can't make a good prediction in the face of a random force without knowing its distribution, since for any supposed matching c value c*, there is a possible pattern of "random" forces that will cause the spring to no longer stop in the desired timeframe. I think it may be beneficial to describe this in terms of the gameplay you want to support. What game mechanic is isomorphic to this spring system?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a Physics question, not a GameDev.

Comment: I think it has its place here, as one might want have the perspective from a game developer, in the context of a physics engine, which may allow some approximation.